# Mac + Composer + PHP-Version disorientation

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an Macbook Pro with PHP installed. I want to install composer packages. By running `composer install` I get the message

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.2 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.2.2].
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.2 requires php ^7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.2 requires php ^7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/migrations v1.5.0 requires ocramius/proxy-manager ^1.0|^2.0 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.2.2].
    - Installation request for doctrine/migrations v1.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/migrations[v1.5.0].
```

But when I run `php -v`, I get

```
PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2018 02:08:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologie
```

How is that possible and how can I fix it?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064160/how-composer-check-php-version

Comment: What does `head -1 $(which composer)` tell you?