# How to switch php version when running composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, acquia

I have composer installed on windows 8.1. I use it to download drupal distributions and modules. I have also installed acquia dev desktop. As you know that dev desktop comes with different versions of php and it has separate folders for it. I have setup composer to use php 5.6. How can I make it use php 7?

Should I uninstall composer and install again or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp/45905822#45905822 may be useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IF you have multiple php version installed in your system

you can run composer with different versions like

In linux

**PHP**

```
    usr/local/php usr/bin/composer install
```

**for PHP 7.1**

```
usr/local/php7.1 /usr/local/composer install
```

actually the idea is which version you wants to run get its bin path and then run the composer.

**In Windows.**

```
path/to/php.exe composer install
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @laravel.levaral Can you please tell me how to use the path? I am using `"C:\Program Files\DevDesktop\php7_0\php.exe" composer create-project markaspot/mark-a-spot project-dir --stability dev` It says `Could not open input file: composer`

Comment: @Umair give it a composer.exe path

Comment: @laravel.levaral How?

Comment: reinstall composer and give it php7 path while installing

Comment: @laravel.levaral Should I uninstall composer installed previously in php 5.6 folder? Or is it ok to have composer installed twice?

Comment: accepted your answer, but I would request/suggest you to make your answer easy to understand

Comment: This guide is enlightening but I have provided quite a detailed answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72476865/7880201) on SO!

Give it a try

Comment: Excellent. Solved for me. I now have an alias for composer8

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to ignore the php version dependency then you can use this -

```
--ignore-platform-reqs
```

### Example:

```
composer require symfony/css-selector --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This way you don't have to edit Environment variables(windows os) or using any full path of php etc. This very useful when I use different php lib from github which requires different php version set in my windows Environment variables though I have all PHP versions in my WAMP server so it will not be any problem running those lib after installing.

Answer (score 6):

In my case worked with this:

```
ea-php72 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update
```

Comment: Perfect! This is it for cPanel/WHM Setups. +1