# Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 6 in a version installable using your PHP version 5.6.30

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer-php, mamp-pro

I’m using mac os and install MAMP 5.7.
when I run PHP -v on the terminal it says PHP version is 7.2
but when I try to create Laravel project I got this error.
I don’t know why the composer recognizes that the PHP version in 5.6

[image: this is the error]

Comment: May be you have multiple php version installed on your system

Comment: @sta would you please tell me how to check that php has installed multiple and how to delete the previous version .?

Comment: Please share your debugging attempts. PHP 5.6 is out of support since months and should not be used any more. And as the error message tells you: Laravel 6 does not support this outdated version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tell Composer to use Different PHP Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the following this may fix the problem

1. check the alias given to composer to point to appropriate version
2. try uninstalling or upgrading your Mammp or your verserver and
   remove cache data.
3. if you change php version in command line. check it after restart of
   your PC

Comment: thank you very much Mr Ali Mashl. the first option has solved my problem.