# How do I get /bin/bash to run the desired php version in Composer?

Tags: php, environment-variables, composer-php, version

```
php -v
```

gives 7.4

```
which php
```

gives 7.4

php test.php with the following test file:

```
<?php
echo phpversion();
?>
```

gives 7.4

But when I run the install/bootup script for Craft CMS, it's executing the file Bootup.php with PHP 5.6.

Under what circumstances will presumably a bash script default to an old php version?  I suspect this could be an environment variable in Composer.  And how do I get it to run using the desired one?

Apologies if I'm asking the [xy question](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can start composer with a specific PHP version using `<path-to-php-bin> composer.phar <options>`. You probably have the command `php` aliased to the newest version, but composer does not know about it.

Comment: @paskl in case you're interested I diagnosed the cause of the problem and have posted my solution as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198753/7799269 . Does your solution solve the problem explained in my answer, do you know?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes Bernie's answer there  covers my scenario. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32752473/7799269

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out the php files in composer have the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

For some reason I don't fully understand, this has the effect of ignoring ALIAS and looking for the first php in $PATH instead.

So the solution I opted for was to find the first php in $PATH, rename it php2 and then using `ln -s` I made a link in that folder called php and pointed it to the correct php version binary, in my case `ln -s /opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php php`

Composer and Craft are now running with the desired php version.

Answer (score -1):

Check in composer.json file if you have set platform

```
"platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    }
```

It's define your target platform you are going to use in project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That said 7.0. but it turns out there was a #! Specifying /home/env php at the start of the file and this led it to the first php in $PATH . So I renamed that to php2 and used ls to point that php to php7.

Comment: That does not help to run scripts with another version of PHP. This setting is only used to resolve dependencies tied to a specific version of PHP