# php version mismatch with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, version, cpanel

I want to install php dependencies in a shared-hosting server, but composer says my php version is `5.6.40` (too old for my dependencies), It was true, so I set the php version from cpanel to `7.3.23` with something called "MultiPHP manager". All right, until I retried to run `composer install`, composer keep saying that my php version is `5.6.40`.

Then I checked the `phpinfo()` in a dummy page and it says my version is `7.3.23`. Also I ran `php -v` and the output says my version is `7.3.23`.

I tried

- reload `httpd`
- run `composer update` and `composer self-update` but it says `allow_url_fopen` is disabled, but I enabled it with a cpanel tool called "MultiPHP INI editor", and `phpinfo()` says that is enabled.

Someone can tell me if im doing something wrong? or how does composer can't use the updated php?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tell Composer to use Different PHP Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version)

Comment: Also, reloading your webserver itself does not affect Composer after all, as this is not run through your webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cli php version (the one you are using for your `composer install`) and the php version your apache is running in your server (the one you see in your `phpinfo()` page) might not match.

Try running this in your console:

```
$ php -v
```

This would output the version you are actually using when running your `composer install`

To run the same version in your server, you might need to locate the PHP 7 binary on your machine (maybe `/usr/bin/php7.3`, you could try to execute a `$ whereis php`), then:

```
/usr/bin/php7.3 /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

This was assuming that your composer binary is under `/user/local/bin/composer`, modify as need.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem working with composer and apache.
Composer were taking my php cli version, not my "php apache version".

You can try:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

But be careful, only if you make sure that you are able to work with the specificated php version.

Another way it could be to force composer to install with the following "hardcode" in your composer.json file:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.3.23"
    }
}
```

You can check more information about composer config schema here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#config

Comment: Hey there!
Using the `--ignore-platform-reqs` has more cons than pros, because it will not only ignore the PHP version constraint, but it will also ignore needed plugins.
For example, a package might need the `php-zip` extension which isn't available on your system, and if you used this flag the package will install but you will probably face issues in your code. So this flag must be used with caution.

Comment: You're totally right @Eyad Bereh. That way must be used with caution, 
I would recommend using a version control system like Git, in order to track changes and have the opportunity to return to a previous point in your project.

Answer (score -1):

change in composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3.2",
......
}
```

it may works

Comment: composer keeps saying my php version is 5 :/

Comment: restart the apatche

Comment: did you mean apache?, I already tried it, I say I reloaded httpd

Comment: No, that won't work, as this does not change the PHP version used to run Composer