# Getting Composer to use the version of PHP installed with Homebrew on Mac

Tags: drupal, composer-php, homebrew

I'm using Composer on a Mac (Big Sur). Running php -v, I get PHP 8.0.12.  This is the version I installed with Homebrew. Composer is using default version of PHP, installed at /usr/bin/php (PHP 7.3.29). I need Composer to use the Homebrew version (/usr/local/Cellar...), but can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tell Composer to use Different PHP Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version)