# Install Laravel 10 via composer when your default PHP version is not 8.1

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-10

Many of us have the problems installing Laravel 10 via composer without using `sudo update-alternatives --config php`.

Default command from Laravel website does not work if you default php version is lower the php8.1 and you want to keep your old php7.4 version.

So if you run `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app` and you have php7.4 ... the Laravel 8 will be installed.

That's why I post here my solution.

Comment: You could also simply call `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and set the right php version

Comment: Worth nothing that the `update-alternatives` command is only for Debian based Linux, though other Linux distributions generally have their own equivalent e.g. RedHas has the `alternatives` command and others you can just install the Debian one and it could work

Comment: "That's why I post here my solution." - so, you don't even have any specific question? Running Composer with different PHP versions has been asked many times before

Comment: @Aless55 that's the idea to NOT use: sudo update-alternatives --config php ... I want to keep my default php7.4 ...

Comment: @NicoHaase please read carefully the title and the issue. Thanks

Comment: So, is this in any way a different problem than the one posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version?

Comment: @NicoHaase I consider it is. As you can see I have top answer over there.  ...

Comment: If this is not the same problem, please share more details. How **exactly** is this different to the other problem? In both cases, running Composer with a different PHP version than the default one resolves the problem

Comment: The enounce of the problem show exactly the difference. If you think is the same I please you explain why do you think is the same.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is what I use to install Laravel 10 via composer:

```
/usr/bin/php8.1 /usr/local/bin/composer create-project laravel/laravel futures
```

Considering you have php 8.1 installed. This works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers - this looks pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52146990

Comment: My friend is not the same problem. As you can see I answered (I have the top answer ) in that link. but anyway. I'll keep this for me.