# How to install a new Laravel project in Valet using a specific PHP version?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I know that you can set a specific PHP version to a directory by using the `valet isolate php@7.2` but I'm not sure how to then install (for example) a Laravel 5.1 project using that specific PHP version.

I know the first reaction will be "just upgrade to a newer version of Laravel", but I've got an old legacy project that I need to get working on the Valet platform. My old MacBook died and the Laravel Homestead platform won't run on my new M1 MacBook.

Comment: "Tell Composer to use Different PHP Version": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version

Comment: (You may be better off with Docker for this, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Install the required PHP version using Homebrew. For example, if you want to use PHP 7.4, run:

```
brew install php@7.4
```

Once the PHP version is installed, switch to it using the following command:

```
valet use php@7.4
```