# Composer does not run with differend php version

Tags: composer-php

I have a dev-server where multiple sites are running in development. Most of them use php8.1

Now for a new project I wanted to run php8.2

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54736948/12848667 and several blog posts I found on the internet, I set my composer to a specific php version. But it does not seem to work.

In composer.json:

```
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "prepend-autoloader": false,
    "platform": {
        "php": "8.2"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "php-version": "composer -vvv about"
},
```

But the output of "php-version" still shows 8.1

```
$ composer php-version
> composer -vvv about
Running 2.4.4 (2022-10-27 14:39:29) with PHP 8.1.18 on Linux / 5.10.0-22-amd64
```

what am I missing?

Edit: php8.2 is installed in fpm and cli version

```
$ which php8.2
/usr/bin/php8.2
```

Comment: please provide the exact error you are getting

Comment: Error? There is no error. composer is running with php8.1 not with php8.2 as stated in composer.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tell Composer to use Different PHP Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version)

Comment: `platform` does not modify which PHP version is used to run Composer

Comment: @NicoHaase as stated in my question, I referred to this answer

Comment: And what did you learn from it? How did you apply it to run Composer using PHP 8.2?

Answer (score -1):

You need to switch from the default version to the desired one.

1. Check default version (it should return 8.1)

> php -v

2. Disable PHP 8.1 module (check output to restart any service)

> sudo a2dismod php8.1

3. Enable PHP 8.2

> sudo a2enmod php8.2

4. Set PHP 8.2 as default version

> sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2

5. For other PHP extensions, set them as default too

> sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar8.2

6. restart Apache

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

7. Check if version is defaulted to 8.2

> php -v

Comment: I did "composer config platform.php 8.2" and it still doesnt use 8.2

Comment: that is bc its still active, check the answer im writing, hope it helps

Comment: `composer config` won't help to run Composer with a different PHP version, nor is`a2enmod` neccessary to run PHP on the shell

Comment: @NicoHaase spit a source too negative

Comment: Feel free to remove the parts from your answer that are not relevant. Afterward, please check whether the remaining answer is already part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version - there's no need to duplicate answers

Comment: Changing the Apache part won’t help in getting composer to use the PHP version. Setting php82 as the alternative should do the trick.